# How to pass back modal dialog confirmation result to calling function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, jquery-ui-dialog

I've added a jquery UI dialog to an mvc page. After the dialog is opened I need to catch the `bool` values if the dialog is *dismissed* or *confirmed*.

So far I have tried to add a call back as mentioned in another answer, but I'm not sure how to pass that value back to the `$('#escalation').on('click', '.delete', function (evt)` so that I may perform a redirect if true.

**Question:**

How can I pass back a bool value to calling function from Jquery UI modal dialog?

**Pseudo code:**

This is my intended flow of execution for the below fuctions:

> 1.Call dialog open on a button click. - (working)
>
> 2.Pass back true or false depending on if the user selected 'ok' or 'cancel' in the modal dialog.
>
> 3.Close the dialog if the returned result to the button click event is false. Otherwise call `window.location.href = RedirectTo;` code.

**Code:**

Dialog markup -

```
                            <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete Selected Record?">
                                <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This record will be permanently deleted.</p> <p>Are you sure?</p>
                            </div>
```

Jquery scripts -

```
<script>
    var baseUri = '@Url.Content("~")';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#escalation').DataTable({
            "order": [[6, "desc"]]
        });


        $('#escalation').on('click', '.delete', function (evt) {
            var cell = $(evt.target).closest("tr").children().first();
            var EscalationID = cell.text();
            var RedirectTo = baseUri + "/EscalationHistory/DeleteEscalation?EscalationID=" + EscalationID;


            ////open dialog 
            evt.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");

            //Need to call this code if the dialog result callback equals true
            window.location.href = RedirectTo;

           //Otherwise do nothing..close dialog
         
        });


        //Dialog opened here, not sure how to pass back the boolean values
        //to the delete click function above
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    callback(true);
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
        });

      
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write your target code inside button click handler or set a flag and use `$(".selector").on("dialogclose", function(event, ui) {});` event handler to check the flag state.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var baseUri = "http://localost";
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false, 
        modal: true, 
        resizable: false, 
        width: 450, 
        open: function() {
            $(this).data("state", "");
        }, 
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $(this).data("state", "confirmed").dialog("close");
            }, 
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        var escalationId = $(this).data("escalation-id");
        var redirectTo = baseUri + "/EscalationHistory/DeleteEscalation?EscalationID=" + escalationId;
        // Use "bind" instead "on" if jQuery < 1.7
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open").on("dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
            if ($(this).data("state") == "confirmed") {
                location.replace(redirectTo);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn" data-escalation-id="123">Delete 123</button>
<button class="btn" data-escalation-id="124">Delete 124</button>
<div id="dialog-confirm" style="display:none">Are you sure?</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But, IMO, logically better to write the code directly in button click handler.

Comment: Can you give an example of how I would use a flag in this case?